# M2e Pro Extension Magento2

Tags: magento2, product-images, watermark

i am using m2epro extension in magento2 currently i am using water mark but its apply on all images i want to apply on just base image how can do that?.

Comment: We use M2E too, but i've no time to check it. I'd suggest to open a support ticket  .... https://clients.m2epro.com/support/